# PostgreSQL update performance with a select

Tags: performance, postgresql, select, sql-update

"Name" is a table with more or less 1 million rows.
I've tried this request but it never ends. Is there an issue to avoid the "in" ?

```
update name 
   set name_val = true 
where name_pk in (select max (name_pk) 
                  from name 
                  group by foreign_key_pk);
```

I'm not against triggers if it's necessary.

Query plan :

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=26073.59..26310.38 rows=200 width=54)"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=26073.59..26075.59 rows=200 width=4)"
"        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=23122.82..24598.20 rows=118031 width=12)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on name  (cost=0.00..19956.21 rows=633321 width=12)"
"  ->  Index Scan using name_pk on name  (cost=0.00..1.16 rows=1 width=54)"
"        Index Cond: (public.name.name_pk = (max(public.name.name_pk)))"
```

2 indexes :

```
CREATE INDEX link_name_foreign_key_pk
  ON name
  USING btree
  (foreign_key_pk);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_pk
  ON name
  USING btree
  (name_pk);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does the execution plan say? Which indexes are defined on the table?

Comment: i've edited my original post.

Comment: For the note, what does `name_pk` represent, and could the query be rewritten like this? http://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks#Fast_specification_of_first_rows_of_some_table_field

Comment: name_pk is the primary key

Comment: Try an index on `(foreign_key_pk, name_pk)` especially with Postgres 9.2 this might help.

Comment: Please remember to always include a **table definition** and your **version of Postgres** for questions like this. For starters, it would have helped to see `NOT NULL` constraints ...

Comment: I'd be interested to know how many unique values of foreign_key_pk there are.

Comment: @erwin : okay i'll do that next time.

Comment: @david : today, about 550k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [multi-column index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) like this (much like [@a_horse already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026884/postgresql-update-performance-with-a-select#comment24611132_17026884) in the comment):

```
CREATE INDEX name_foo_id ON name (foreign_key_pk, name_pk DESC)
```

`DESC` makes is only slightly faster. Postgres can scan indexes backwards almost as fast. But it might get tricky with multi-column indexes.

And use this alternative syntax for the [`UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html):

```
UPDATE name n
SET    name_val = TRUE
FROM  (
    SELECT max(name_pk) AS max_pk
    FROM   name 
    GROUP  BY foreign_key_pk
  ) x
WHERE n.name_pk = x.max_pk
AND   name_val IS DISTINCT FROM TRUE;
```

`IN` tends to be the slowest possible solution for bigger sets. A `JOIN` should be faster.

The additional `WHERE` clause `AND name_val IS DISTINCT FROM TRUE` avoids (expensive) empty updates.

An anti-semi-join with `NOT EXISTS` might be a contender for the performance crown, too:

```
UPDATE name n
SET    name_val = TRUE
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   name
   WHERE  foreign_key_pk = n.foreign_key_pk
   AND    name_pk > n.name_pk
   )
AND    name_val IS DISTINCT FROM TRUE;
```

Comment: Good job, it works perfectly ! For information, the second request is 20% faster. Thanks.